# WordPress head referencing issue, wp_enqueue_style won't call my css stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress, user-interface

Here is my current code:

```
<?php function medsource_register_styles(){

wp_enqueue_style('medsource-style', get_template_directory_uri()."/style.css", array('medsource-bootstrap') , '1.0' , 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style('medsource-bootstrap', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", array() , '1.0' , 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style('medsource-fontawesome', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css", array() , '1.0' , 'all' );}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'medsource_register_styles');
?>
```

Not sure why it isn't working, the enqueue styles work for my boostrap, medsource-bootsrap and medsource-fontawesome but can't seem to make it work for my style.css stylesheet
Here is also a screenshot of my files:
[image: Files]

I don't think its a problem with calling wp_head since the bootstrap and fontawesome works fine. For context, I used the front-page.php to call wp_head. Thanks !

Comment: if you're using `get_template_directory_uri()` in a child theme it will return the path to the parent theme. use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead

Comment: Tried this already, but it still doesn't seem to work, and I believe I'm not using a parent theme since I'm creating the theme from scratch. Thanks tho !

Comment: Look at your browser devtools Network tab. Do any stylesheets fail to load with 404? What paths do they come from?